# How to Auto Post Feed on Facebook Page In Asp Dot Net Core with Angular(Boilerplate)?

Tags: asp.net-core, angular6, aspnetboilerplate

I want to auto post feed on Facebook.When i added some new entry then it will shown on m Facebook page

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no Facebook SDK for .NetCore yet. You may have a look at [this](https://piotrgankiewicz.com/2017/02/06/accessing-facebook-api-using-c/) to implement it yourself